# Can't change password on my Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, passwords

In our school, they gave us little computers to do our homework on and stuff like that (and we paid like 300 for them, and we get to keep them for life). Anyway, my sister found out my password and is clogging it up with pictures of her self (because she just annoys me for the sake of it). Anyway, since the school pretty much made it so you can't do anything like change passwords etc so can anyone tell me how to change the password? I've tried so many things. I've even managed to get into an Administrator account, but it still won't let me. 
Oh and by getting into the admin account I can use the Command prompt but I can't do very much on there.
And the Maximum password age is 30, but I can't change it. 
Thanks in advance :)

P.S. Please don't say stuff about getting into trouble for changing the password. I can do it, and I don't see how they can punish us for doing it (and we paid for them so they are 100% ours)

Comment: "I've tried so many things" Please elaborate.  What happens when you go to the user account settings and try to change your password there? Have you considered just asking your school about it? I have trouble believing they'd have a problem with your changing your password. :)

Comment: Why not ask for help at school?

Comment: You might have to be connected to the school network in order to change the password

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Besides the school network thing, they may want to keep access to the laptops even if the students "own" them for their own administrative or "safety" purposes. This seems a common thing with school laptops.

Answer (score 0):

A typical solution would be to:

1. Log in as an Administrator.
2. Open an elevated command prompt.

You can run an elevated command prompt via *Search* -> "cmd" (no quotes) then select *Command Prompt* (making sure to right-click -> *Run as Administrator*).

[image: Windows 8 Command Prompt Search]

3. Run the `net` command.

Windows Vista and later can make use of the net command:

```
   net user {username} /Passwordchg:yes
```

This should allow you to change your password normally.

Another option is to simply blank the password before changing it normally:

```
net user {username} ""
```

*Note*: `{username}` (no curly braces) is the corresponding username you wish to change (e.g. "superballs" — again, no quotes). Obviously press <kbd>Enter</kbd> afterwards.

Since you mentioned password age, it is probably worth considering that there is (apparently) a bug that can affect Windows 8 passwords that have expired which prevents them from being changed. To my knowledge, there is no fix for this.

Comment: When I type "net user" on the Administrator account, my account does not show up. So I cannot change the password on it. I've tried this command on all the account available to try, but unfortunately this cannot be done. I still cannot change the password. Thanks very much for your help though! :)

Comment: Sorry that didn't help. Well, as one more (somewhat extremes) option, you might want to have a look at Offline NT Password and Registry Editor -- http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/ -- It technically allows editing of passwords on the disk, though personally, I have never done anything really except blank them (which may or may not solve this issue) for locked accounts. You will want to pay attention to making sure you select the right things and actually apply the settings you choose though. Other than that, its pretty easy to use. In any case, good luck. =P